# Kotlin Android, хранение логина и пароля для API авторизации

Tags: android, kotlin

Пишу приложение для работы с API, в котором выполняется авторизация пользователей по логину и паролю. Логин и пароль нужно будет вводить при каждом запуске приложения или после н-минут бездействия. Приложение пишу на котлине с использованием библиотеки ретрофит.
Возник вопрос: где и как хранить логин и пароль пользователя для последующего использования его api-запросах?

Comment: вопрос по котлину, а не жаве

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще по поводу статики понравилась [статья на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/company/funcorp/blog/430836/) возможно чем-то поможет в решении вопроса

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]